# "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass" when creating new instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, associations, relationship

I'm having an issue within rails where, I have a basic many to many relationship between two models (order and status). These models look like the following:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, :through => :lines
  has_and_belongs_to_many :statuses

  default_scope order("#{table_name}.created_at desc")
end
```

and

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders

end
```

Within my index view for orders, I'm displaying the Order's most recent status, so order.statuses.last.name, however, when I create a new Order, I receive an error. This error is for an undefined method name, as the new orders are not having any relationship when they're first created.

My question is, is there a way to initialize a relationship between my two models, before saving a new order? I'd want my orders to always at least have the first status in my statuses collection, but don't want used to have to manually check it before saving.

The error for good measures is:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

for this line in my view:

```
<td><%= order.statuses.last.name %></td>
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Well, in order to initialize the `statuses` you either have to hard code it or hit the database. So why not just save and then move on? Unless you cache the array of statuses and initialize your order that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should take care if there is no last status or the last status doesn't have name

```
<td><%= order.statuses.last.try(:name) %></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix:

```
<td><%= order.statuses.last.name if order.statuses %></td>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. Playing around this, for my certain situation has had mix results. I'm able to successfully do the following: <td><%= order.statuses.last if order.statuses %></td> - but I cannot do <td><%= order.statuses.last.name if order.statuses %></td>. My guess is that it's because the .name method is coming from my status model, and it still does not know how to respond if this is nil? I think I have to initialize a relationship before saving for this .name method to be recognized? Once again, thank you very much, I truly appreciate the help.

Comment: So a status can exist without a name? In that case, you may want to include that in your condition: `order.statuses.last.name if order.statuses.last.name`